# Arrange JSON in tree structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have a plain JSON that contasins the id's of its dependentant's objects..

```
 var array1=  

    [
        {
            "id": 84,
            "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
            "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": null,
            "isRemoved": false,
            "isPrimary": false
        },
        {
            "id": 95,
            "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
            "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": 84,
            "isRemoved": false,
            "isPrimary": false
        },
        {
            "id": 150,
            "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
            "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": 95,
            "isRemoved": false,
            "isPrimary": false
        },
        {
            "id": 160,
            "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
            "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": 95,
            "isRemoved": false,
            "isPrimary": false
        }
    ]
```

I wanted to convert to the below format by identifying the "id" and "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId" and pushing it into a new array called 
    **items**

```
var array1=

    [{
        "id": 84,
        "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
        "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": null,
        "isRemoved": false,
        "isPrimary": false,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 95,
                "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
                "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": 84,
                "isRemoved": false,
                "isPrimary": false,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 150,
                        "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
                        "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": 95,
                        "isRemoved": false,
                        "isPrimary": false,
                        "items": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 160,
                        "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
                        "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": 95,
                        "isRemoved": false,
                        "isPrimary": false,
                        "items": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

The code that I tried is given below...
I created a dummy object first in the new format:

```
var dummyObj= {
        "id": 84,
        "outputTypeId": 900000000000002,
        "previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId": null,
        "isRemoved": false,
        "isPrimary": false
    }
function populateObj(array1, arrObj) {
   for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i].id == arrObj.parentActivityId) {
            array1[i].items.push(arrObj);
        } else {
            populateObj(array1[i].items, arrObj);
        }
    }
};

populateObj(dummyObj);
```

Since I don't want to hardcode a dummy object in the beginning.
Is there any way to achieve this conversion using javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you shouldn't do that. The first JSON is great data struct. Items keep linked via logic mapping id, which can reveal easily by Array.filter().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function group(arr) {
    var t={};
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (!obj.id) throw 'object found without id!';
        t[obj.id]=obj;
    });
    var result=[];
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (!obj.previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId) {
            result.push(obj);
        } else {
            var parent=t[obj.previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId];
            if (!parent) throw('parent with id '+obj.previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId+' not found!');
            var items=parent.items;
            if (!items) {
                items=[];
                parent.items=items;
            }
            items.push(obj);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done quite easily with a few functions and a bit of recursion.

The first function takes the entire source array a source object and adds the `items` property:

```
function createObject(sourceArray, obj)
{
    obj.items = createArray(sourceArray, obj.id);
  return obj;
}
```

That in turn uses another function to filter the source array for the children:

```
function createArray(sourceArray, id){
    return sourceArray.filter(function(e){
                                return e.previousOutputTypeActivitySeqMappingId == id;
                             })
                             .map(function(e){
                                 return createObject(sourceArray,e);
                             })
}
```

You'll note that in tun that calls back to the `createObject` function to recursively continue building the tree.

The final part is to kick it all of by looking for items with `null` parent values

```
var result = createArray(input,null);
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/3epjb93j/